# Datetime can't insert into database?

Tags: php

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label">DateTime Picking</label>
<div class="controls input-append date form_datetime" data-date="" data date-format="d M yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
<input size="25" type="text" value="" readonly>
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" /><br/>
</div>
```

and this:

```
$sql1="insert into task(date,create_date) value('STR_TO_DATE('$_POST[date1]','%d/%m/%Y '),NOW());
$conn->Execute($sql1);
```

Why can't I insert into the database with the datetime format.

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: How to i convert this (data date-format="d M yyyy - HH:ii p") to insert into sql..?

Comment: ('STR_TO_DATE('$_POST[date1]','%d/%m/%Y ') it is correct format to insert into my database?

Comment: store it as EPOCH

Answer (score -1):

It is better practice to use Quotation for every fields. Because it could be conflict with MySQL Reserved keywords.

**Example :**

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(`date`,`create_date`) VALUES('VALUE1','VALUE2');
```

In your problem, If you set `DATETIME` datatype for your `date` and `create_date` fields. Then you have to make sure your it's value should be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format to confirm `DATETIME` datatype

Also change your Query to -

```
$date = ''; #Confirm your Datetime format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` here, if this field is 'DATETIME' datatype
$sql1="INSERT INTO task(`date`,`create_date`) VALUES('$date',NOW());
$conn->Execute($sql1);
```

> **NOTE :** In Your Query String you can also use `VALUE('value1','value2')` or `VALUES('value1','value2')`

Comment: `Date` is **not** a reserved word ~ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: Also, you can use `VALUE` or `VALUES`. MySQL supports both ~ https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Answer (score -1):

```
**Always remember MySQL accept only date format in Y-m-d H:i:s format**
There is mismatch in your single and double quotes try following  line of code 
$sql1="insert into task(date,create_date) value(STR_TO_DATE('".$_POST['date1']."','%d/%m/%Y'),NOW())";
$conn->Execute($sql1);
```

OR You can also try below code

```
$date1 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['date1']));

$sql1="insert into task(date,create_date) value('".$date1."',NOW())";
$conn->Execute($sql1);
```